# Nodejs deepstream connection failure

Tags: node.js, deepstream.io

I am currently following some NodeJS & Deepstream.io.client-js tutorials. But an error occurs while trying to login to the server. I have no idea what that error means but here it is!

```
const express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  ds = require('deepstream.io-client-js'),
  app = express();

 // Create deepstream client
 const client = ds('wss://154.deepstreamhub.com?apiKey=xxx');
 client.login();
```

The error I get :

```
 Error: connectionError: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain (C)
at Client._$onError (C:\Users\xdidemk\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\deepstream.io-client-js\dist\lib\client.js:204:11)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\xdidemk\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\deepstream.io-client-js\dist\lib\message\connect
 ion.js:315:19)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

Comment: Unable to help you myself here, but I'd recommend jumping into the deepstream Slack chat and asking there.

Comment: try connecting with ws  protocol instead of wss, looks like the problem is in your ssl certificate 
also check ssl config variables in your config file, they should be set to null unless you have valid ssl certificate : 
`sslKey: null 
sslCert: null
sslCa: null
`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this?

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
```